# Javascript not caching in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've been running into this issue on only IE. From what I've managed to narrow the problem down to, it looks like the javascript just isn't caching in it. As soon as I clear the cache, all the functions become usable, but after that, if I close the browser and reopen it back to the site, it all goes back to being non-functional.

Is this an IE bug or am I on the wrong track here, like is it not the cache or not in the way that I'm thinking it is?

Comment: "all the functions become usable" - what happens when they aren't "usable"? Do you get an exception? A specific message you can share? What versions of IE? What do your code look like for including scripts? Include any/weird meta tags? I've never had/seen a problem like this, so...

Comment: Please clarify your question. Cache has typically very little influence on JavaScript behavior. I also know of no IE related bugs that would come up due to caching. It seems more like a timing / dependency issue.